# Use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in office 365 add in

Tags: office365, vsto, office-js, office365api

I am converting my VSTO add in to office 365 using office.js. now i want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word functionality to office.js like

```
private Word.Document Doc;

Doc.Styles;

Doc.Variables[" "]
```

is there any way to use this in my office.js? or is there any way to convert my VSTO add in to office add in ?

Comment: No, and no. You can use your basic knowledge of how Word and its object model works to *understand* how to use the Office JS APIs. But you have to read through the documentation and go through the learning curve. Some things aren't even covered (yet) in the JS APIs and have no direct equivalent. For example, it's not possible to *create or modify* styles, although existing styles can be applied. Doc Variables are not supported at all.

Comment: You might find this of interest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/migrate-vsto-to-office-add-in-shared-code-library-tutorial